# Can't Drag & Drop text to unity launcher (e.g. url's, highlighted text)

Tags: unity, launcher, mime-type, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a unity launcher icon (.dekstop file) on which you can drop any (selected/highlighted) text from a web browser, google chrome in my case.

I know you can use the "MimeType=" key in a .desktop file, but I can't find the right mime type for my scenario. I've tried several text MimeTypes and "text/*", but none of them would work.

Does anyone know which MimeType I have to use in order for my launcher icon to accept text when hovering over it?

Comment: the launcher sounds interesting..!! cant help but would love to have the launcher! gr8 idea :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't drag/drop arbitrary clipboard contents onto launchers. The MimeType entry in the .desktop file specifies what file and content types the application can open, for the MIME system, and is as I understand the code, not used by the drag and drop handling. However, rather, the content of the drop is simply passed as an argument to the program, and must be a URI or file path, replacing %u, %U, %f, or %F, as specified in the Desktop Entry Specification, here: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables

Comment: I found that the MimeType key is actually necessary in Unity 2D.